# How to pass parameters into blade or {{ }}?

Tags: php, laravel, parameter-passing, laravel-blade, pusher

sorry for my poor English. I'm from Taiwan.

Origin code

```
        var channel = pusher.subscribe('question-channel');
        channel.bind('question-event', function (data) {

                var n = new Notification(data.title, {
                    icon: 'img/icon.png',
                    body: data.content,
                    image:'img/1.jpg'
                });

                n.onclick = function(e) { 
                    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab
                    window.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000/'); 
                }

        });
```

I want make it be

```
        var channel = pusher.subscribe('question-channel');
        channel.bind('question-event', function (data) {

            if({{\App\Models\UserAreas::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->where('area_id','=',data.area)}})
                var n = new Notification(data.title, {
                    icon: 'img/icon.png',
                    body: data.content,
                    image:'img/1.jpg'
                });

                n.onclick = function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab
                    window.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
                }

        });
```

but,
I can't pass the parameter(data.area) into {{ }}

I have to do this, in order to confirm that the posted is one of the expertise of the currently logged-in user.

Comment: `data.error` is a JS variable, and you can't use it in a PHP function (`{{ }}` is a wrapper that executes PHP code). By the time `data.error` is available, the code in `{{ }}` will have executed long ago. This is one of the differences between Front-End (Client) and Back-End (Server) code.

Comment: oh...I see! thanks u, but if I can't do this, how can I confirm that the posted is one of the expertise of the currently logged-in user. I meaning... how to check the data.area with database?

Comment: No problem :) Unfortunately, I'm not an expert on Pusher, but you'll have to figure out an alternative way to perform that check, maybe as an AJAX request, or setting a JS variable beforehand, etc etc. Also sorry, can't read today, I meant `data.area`, not `data.error` in my first comment 

Comment: It's ok! I know that. really thanks u ^_^
I hope my poor English and google translate didn't offend you. T_T

Comment: @TimLewis 
I successfully solved it!
Through ajax, thanks for your tips. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

1. Pass your data into the view and from PHP to JS:

Where you call your view:

```php
use \App\Models\UserAreas;

// ...

    $userAreas = UserAreas::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->get();
    return view('path/to/your/view', [ 'userAreas' => $userAreas ]);
```

Inside your view:

```php
        var userAreas = @json($userAreas);
        var channel = pusher.subscribe('question-channel');
        channel.bind('question-event', function (data) {

            if(userAreas.filter((area) => area.area_id === data.area).length)
                var n = new Notification(data.title, {
                    icon: 'img/icon.png',
                    body: data.content,
                    image:'img/1.jpg'
                });

                n.onclick = function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab
                    window.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
                }

        });
```

---

2. Use an API endpoint

api.php

```php
use \App\Models\UserAreas;

// ...

Route::get('user-areas/{{userArea}}', function(int $userArea) {
    return (bool) UserAreas::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('area_id', $userArea)->count();
});
```

your-view.blade.php

```php
        var channel = pusher.subscribe('question-channel');
        channel.bind('question-event', function (data) {

            fetch('api/user-areas/' + data.area).then(function(exists) {
                if(exists) {
                    var n = new Notification(data.title, {
                        icon: 'img/icon.png',
                        body: data.content,
                        image:'img/1.jpg'
                    });

                    n.onclick = function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab
                        window.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: I'll try it.
It seem so interesting!
cuz I never used this method.. about api and fetch('api/user-areas/'+data)
very thanks for ur answer!

Comment: Apart from that, the most important thing, I hope my poor English and google translate didn't offend you. T_T

Comment: Not at all. Don't worry about that :)