# JavaScript escape sequence cannot read a variable value while concatenation?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, string-concatenation

I am working in a Laravel application. I want to concatenate a variable with a string using escape sequence (`` ` ` ``) in JS. A normal concatenation of strings and variable work fine using escape sequence. But it does not work and throws error when I concatenate PHP route string with a parameter. You will have an idea when you see the below code.

```
<script>
 function changeStatus(value, applicationId){
        var url = `"{{route('application.toggle.approval',['id'=> ${applicationId} ])}}"`;
        console.log(url);
 }
</script>
```

I am not being able to pass any kind of variable there. It is giving me error like below:

```
(2/2) ErrorException
Use of undefined constant applicationId - assumed 'applicationId' (View: C:\wamp64\www\oibn\app\Modules\Application\Views\applicationShowProtected.blade.php)
```

How do I pass the variable there? I can console.log the parameters passed in the function. But that value is not getting passed in concatenation. It gives error only. Please help.

Comment: Looks like you expect PHP to run on the client. That is a misunderstanding. PHP generates the HTML, and then it is all up to JavaScript. PHP does not know about `applicationId`, yet it must execute *before* JavaScript gets to do its thing. Seems you want the reverse, and have JavaScript run first, and then PHP to run on *every* call of that JS function. It doesn't work that way. PHP will run when you make a server request.

Comment: Does that help you solving your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67876244/how-to-pass-parameters-into-blade-or/67883117#67883117

Comment: Yes it will help me solve the problem. I am not executing any php there in js, I am not concatenating a string  with a variable. If i define some variable and just concatenate in that string, it wont work, I am just concatenating a string and logging it in console.

Comment: I am simply working with the JS. I am just dealing with an string. Doesn't matter whatever it is inside the string, it is javascript only. Simply concatenating a variable with some value to a string. Concatenating a variable with other strings work fine but concatenating with that particular string does not work.

Comment: You're trying to take a JavaScript variable `applicationId` available at the client side, and use it in the blade template`{{route...`, which is built on the serverside. An impossible situation, however if you want to just escape `{` within blade  you can probably do `@{`